# turf's mask() function does not run with 10 or more polygons

Tags: javascript, geospatial, geo, turfjs

I can not run the `turf.mask()` function with more than 9 randomly created points. It just does not return any result.

```
import { featureCollection, polygon } from '@turf/helpers';
import createCircle from '@turf/circle';
import createMask from '@turf/mask';

const howManyCircles = 9;

const cover = polygon([
    [[-180, -90], [180, -90], [180, 90], [-180, 90], [-180, -90]]
],
    { name: 'cover' });
const bbox = [83.16964204361335,83.47466091885153,-83.16964204362385,-83.47466091885192];
const randomPoints = randomPoint(howManyCircles, { bbox: bbox });
const radius = 1000;
const options = { steps: 64, units: 'kilometers', properties: { foo: 'bar' } };
    const circles = randomPoints.features.map(points => {
        return createCircle(points.geometry.coordinates, radius, options);
    });
const mask = createMask(featureCollection(circles), cover);
```

This works as expected. There are nine holes (created through the `randomPoints()` function) in the polygon.
However, as soon as I change `howManyCircles` to a number greater than `9`, I do not get any result. It calculates and calculates but does not come to an end. Here is a fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/6m3qsnu1/

Why is that?

"@turf/helpers": "^6.3.0",
"@turf/random": "^6.3.0",
"@turf/turf": "^6.3.0",

Comment: So for less than 9 it works fine?

Comment: @EvgenyKlimenchenko 9 and less, yes.

Comment: I looked at all the documentation there, I don't think they have some kind of limit there. Seems like a bug in the code. I also saw you did created an issue in github as well, I am sure that would be the best place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug and got fixed in `v7`. However, `yarn add @turf/turf` or `npm i @turf/turf` installs `turf 6.3.0`. In order to install the most recent version use `npm i turf@7.0.0-alpha.1`